# Unclear casting in C

Tags: c, casting

I was surprised why I get different results.

```
    uint16_t wCaptureTime = 35;

    wDeltaTime1 = (uint16_t) - (int16_t)wCaptureTime;
    wDeltaTime2 =  0xFFFF - (int16_t)wCaptureTime;

    printf("wDeltaTime1 %d \n", wDeltaTime1);
    printf("wDeltaTime2 %d \n", wDeltaTime2);
```

The code results in:

```
wDeltaTime1 65501 
wDeltaTime2 65500
```

Could someone explain or give some link to read about that behaviour.

Comment: Are you sure for the `wDeltaTime1`definition?

Comment: Anyway, this code will behave differently depending on CPU register size = the size of `int`. 32 bit? Less than 32 bit?

Answer (score 6):

The `(uint16_t)` in the expression `(uint16_t) - (int16_t)wCaptureTime` is a *cast*. When `-35` is cast to `uint16_t` you get `-35 + 65536` which is `65501`.

If `sizeof(int)` is 2 then `0xFFFF - (int16_t)wCaptureTime` is `65535 - 35` in `unsigned` arithmetic which is `65500`. If `sizeof(int)` is 4 then you'll get the same result, although the expression will be evaluated in signed (`int`) arithmetic.

Answer (score 3):

Supposing that the implementation uses 32-bit `int`, and `wDeltaTime1` is an `int`, then the operations in `DeltaTime1 = (uint16_t) - (int16_t)wCaptureTime;` are:

- The `(int16_t)` cast converts the `uint16_t` `wCaptureTime` to `int16_t`. The value remains 35.
- This `int16_t` is automatically promoted to `int`. The value remains 35.
- The unary `-` operator negates the value, producing −35.
- The `(uint16_t)` cast converts it to `uint16_t`. Conversion to `uint16_t` is performed modulo 65536, so the result is −35 + 65536 = 65501.
- This `uint16_t` converted to the type of `wDeltaTime1`, `int`. The value is 65501.
- This value is assigned to `wDeltaTime1`, producing 65501 in `wDeltaTime1`.

The operations in `wDeltaTime2 =  0xFFFF - (int16_t)wCaptureTime;` are:

- `0xFFFF` is an `int` constant with value 65535.
- The `(int16_t)` cast converts the `uint16_t` `wCaptureTime` to `int16_t`. The value remains 35.
- This `int16_t` is automatically promoted to `int`. The value remains 35.
- The binary `-` operator subtracts 35 from 65535, producing 65535 − 35 = 65500.
- This value is assigned to `wDeltaTime2`, producing 65500 in `wDeltaTime2`.

One source of confusion you may have is that negation in `uint16_t` is equivalent to subtracting from 65536, not 65535 (or `0xFFFF`). 65535 is the “all ones” pattern in 16 bits; it does not act like zero. 65536 is where `uint16_t` wraps around, so it acts more like zero.

The bitwise complement operator, `~`, would change (considering just the low 16 bits) 35 to 65500.

Comment: @Lundin: Thanks, there are actually a few places the automatic promotion does not occur. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, you are casting -35 to `uint16_t`. This is 65501:

```
- (uint16_t) 35 = 65501 (as an uint16_t)
```

In the second case, the first operand is 0xffff (65535) so you are getting 65535 - 35 = 65550:

```
65535 - (uint16_t) 35 = 65500
```

Comment: No, there are no implicit operands in C.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: I think he means `-x` is implicitly `0-x`, not that I agree with that presentation.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, there can be an implicit first operand only if the operator is interpreted as *binary* `-`, whereas of course it is *unary* `-`.  That the result is algebraically equivalent to subtracting the single operand from 0 is a weak leg to stand on, in part because algebraic equivalence does always confer computational equivalence, and in part because the two operators have different precedence.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: I am not speaking of the C operators. Mathematically, −x is 0-x.

Comment: This answer is misleading. In the second case, the first operand is `0xFFFF`, which will fit inside an `int` or otherwise an `unsigned int`. It will always be a positive value and never get treated as `-1` on any system, unless explicitly cast to a signed type.

Answer (score 1):

Line 1:

- `(int16_t)wCaptureTime;` triggers an explicit conversion to `int16_t`. The value `35` is preserved.
- `-(int16_t)wCaptureTime;` applies the unary `-` operator. In case of 32 bit or larger computer, `wCaptureTime` is integer promoted to `int`. In case of 8/16 bit computers, the type remains `int16_t` .
- `(uint16_t)-(int16_t)wCaptureTime;` triggers an explicit conversion of the negative value to `uint16_t`. This conversion happens as per C17 6.3.1.3:

  > Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of the new type.

  On a 2's complement 32 bit computer `-35` will yield `0xFFDD` = `65501`.

Line 2:

- `0xFFFF` is of type `unsigned int` on a 8/16 bit CPU but of type `int` on a 32 or larger bit CPU.
- In case `0xFFFF` is `unsigned int`, then the operand `(int16_t)wCaptureTime;` will get promoted to `unsigned int` too (regardless of the cast) - because of "the usual arithmetic conversions". In which case the same signed to unsigned conversion as in line 1 occurs and you end up with something like unsigned arithmetic `65535 - 0xFFDD` = 34 decimal.
- In case `0xFFFF` is `int`, then the operand `(int16_t)wCaptureTime;` will get promoted to `int`. The operation is simply carried out with two `int` operands, `65535 - 35 = 65500`.

Study [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) and [implicit type promotion rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules).

Also, the types of integer contant matters. Most often they are `int` but in case of hex integer constants, they can also be `unsigned int` depending on value.

Comment: Conversion of −35 to `uint16_t` is defined by the C standard (6.3.1.3 2, modulo), not implementation-defined.

Comment: You’re late to the party but I think this is a particularly good answer.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yeah true, it is the format that's implementation-defined (2's compl)